# can logstash server read data from resturl

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-forwarder

I want to read data from resturl and feed that in logstash server. i did google and found [a link] https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-http_poller

Logstash version - logstash-1.4.5-1_a2bacae.noarch
plugin- https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-http_poller

I tried it with my ELK setup but its is not working for me. while installing plugin (step 2.2)  `bin/plugin install /home/elk/logstash-input-http_poller/logstash-input-http_poller-2.0.3.gem`
 it returned me

> Can only install contrib at this time... Exiting.

When I start investigating my "plugin" script that i got from logstash rpm is very specific about $2 argument that can only be "contrib" if $2 is not "contrib" script will exit right away. So as per tutorial instruction section 2.2 passing your plugin gem file will always fail.

Can some one help me in this, i do'nt know what i'm missing to run it.

Answer (score 1):

They split all the plugins into different ruby gems in version 1.5.  You can see that reflected in [the source](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/1.5/bin/plugin) to bin/plugin.